# bind9 reverse zone dns config error - CNAME

Tags: domain-name-system, configuration, bind, reverse-dns, dns-zone

i am trying to set up a reverse zone for my bind dns server,
under the subnet 192.168.0.65/29
my zone datafile looks like this:

```
   @       IN      SOA     server.example.com.   server.example.com.   (
                            2014101300 ; serial
                            1000       ; refresh
                            180        ; retry
                            180        ; expire
                            10         ; minimum
                            )

    65      IN      CNAME   65.64/29
    66      IN      CNAME   66.64/29
    67      IN      CNAME   67.64/29
    68      IN      CNAME   68.64/29

    66      IN      NS      server.example.com.

    65      IN      PTR     router.example.com.
    66      IN      PTR     server.example.com.
    67      IN      PTR     client-1.example.com.
    68      IN      PTR     client-2.example.com.
```

When i try to load this file it fails and displays the following error: "CNAME and other data". Any ideas to what might have gone wrong??

Comment: Can you clarify if this supposed to represent a reverse zone for 192.168.0.0/24 where you are trying to delegate a zone for 192.168.0.64/29 (based on https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2317) or if this a supposed to represent such a rfc2317-style zone for 192.168.0.64/29. The included zone data looks like a mix of the two.

Answer (score 2):

The CNAME records should be in your `0.168.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA.` zone.  It should also have glue records for the `64/27.23.168.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA.` zone to which you are delegating.

```
65        IN  CNAME   65.64/29.0.168.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA. ;qualified
66        IN  CNAME   66.64/29 ;unqualified name
67        IN  CNAME   67.64/29
```

The zone for `64/27.23.168.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA.` should contain the rest of the records.  If you are doing this on the same DNS server, you can omit the glue and `NS` records.

See [How to Delegate Reverse Subnet Maps](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch9/reverse.html) records for documentation and examples. RFC 2317, Classless IN-ADDR.ARPA delegation, has already been linked to.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `65 IN CNAME 65.65/29.0.168.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA.` instead ?

Comment: @XavierLucas In this case yes, the values were copied from the referenced documentation.  The 27 or 29 doesn't matter much other than a reference to the size of the delegation. 64/29 indicates a subnet of 8 addresses starting at 64.  64/27 indicates a subnet of 32 addresses starting at 64, which could then be re-delegated as 64/29 and addition subnets.

Answer (score 1):

The right hand side of a CNAME record should be a canonical name not something that looks like a CIDR address. See for instance [RFC 2181](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181) for clarification.

A more logical zone file would be one without all the CNAME RR records you have there.

Answer (score 0):

Your Zonefile lists these entries for 66:

```
66      IN      CNAME   66.64/29
66      IN      NS      server.example.com.
66      IN      PTR     server.example.com.
```

So you do not only have a CNAME-record, but an NS and PTR as well, whis is explicitly forbidden. A CNAME "redirects" all queries (MX, A,...), so you may not override these by specifying additional resource records.

Apart from this, your zone file looks a little awkward to me; after the SOA-Record, I'd only expect this kind of entries:

```
@       IN      NS      server.example.com.

65      IN      PTR     router.example.com.
66      IN      PTR     server.example.com.
67      IN      PTR     client-1.example.com.
68      IN      PTR     client-2.example.com.
```

<strike>By the way, your CNAME's right hand side seems weird to me, "65.64/29.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa." will most probably not be resolvable (slashes not being allowed AFAIK), but I'm pretty sure, your setup won't need these CNAMEs.</strike>

Comment: Read [RFC2317](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2317.txt)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I didn't yet need CIDR reverse delegation yet. Striked this part of my answer.